# How do you prevent CSS div from dislocating or collapsing when resizing the browser?

Tags: javascript, css

How do you prevent the whole website from resizing whenever you minimize your browser or maximize, webiste size adjust directly proportional to your resize. How to prevent this from happening? without re-organizing everything? I need the site length to be still even if you resize or maximize

Please Help. Thank you.

here's what i've done so far:
markup:

```
<div id="table">

<div class="tabs" id="content1">   
   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
       <label for="tab-1">Home</label>
       <div class="content">
       <p></p>  

           <!-- <div id="contentheader"></div> -->

            <div id="caption">
                <p> Title Goes Here</p>
                        </div>

            <div id="nextcontent">
                <p>Words go Here</p>
                        </div>

       </div> <!--end of content tag -->



   </div><!--end of content tab tag for TAB1 -->

   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-2">About Us</label>

       <div class="content">
           <p>Stuff for Tab Two</p>


           <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/100">
       </div>
   </div>

   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-3">Forum</label>

       <div class="content">
           <p>Stuff for Tab Three</p>


       </div>
   </div>

    <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-4" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-4">Gallery</label>

       <div class="content">
           <p>Stuff for Tab Four</p>

           <img src="http://placedog.com/200/100">
       </div>
   </div>

   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-5" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-5">Forum</label>

       <div class="content">
           <p>Stuff for Tab Five</p>

           <img src="http://placedog.com/200/100">
       </div>
   </div>


   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-6" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-6">Sign up</label>

       <div class="content">
           <p>Stuff for Tab Six</p>

           <img src="http://placedog.com/200/100">
       </div>
           </div>
           </div><!--*end of table tag -->
     <div id="footer">
       &copy; All rights reserved 2013
</div>
```

javascript-code:

```
*
{      margin: 0px;   }

#table
{
        font-size:100%;
        min-height: 80%;
        /* height: autopx; */
        min-width: 100%;
        /*background: #aac6e9;  */
         /*background color of the whole layout*/
}


.tabs {
  position: relative;  
  min-height: 80%; /* adjust height of the body */
  min-width: 80%;

  margin: 100px 50px 0px 50px;  /* top, right, bottom, left */



}

.tab  
{
  float: left; /* this is responsible for tabs to align left */


}
.tab label {
  background:#202d00; /*bg color of all menu bar item */
  padding: 10px 40px; /* menu bar item height width */
  color:#FFF;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-left: -1px;
  position: relative;
  left: 1px;
  top: -29px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .17s linear;
  font-weight:bold;


}
.tab [type=radio]
{
  display: none;  



}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0px; /* former 20 space between the menu bar and content text */
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .6s linear;
  opacity: 0;
  color:#396; /*Text color of Title Goes Here*/
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:36px;
  background-color:#f8fed2; /*bg color of the content body holder text */





        /*width:100%;
        height:92%;
        */


}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background: #c5de10; /*bg color of active menu bar item */
  border-bottom: 0px solid white;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #202d00;


}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

#footer
{
        /*margin-top:10%;*/
        height: 20px;
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;

}



/*#contentheader
{
        background-image:url('1.jpg');
        width:100%;
        height: 18%;

} */

#content1
{
        width:80%; /*adust the width of content body*/
        height:80%;
        /*border: 3px solid red; */
        margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
        border: thin outset;
        background-color: #f8fed2;



}

#nextcontent
{
        color: black;
        font-size:16px;
        margin-left:20px;
        margin-right:20px;
        margin0bottom:2px;
        margin-top:10px;


}

#caption
{
        margin-left:10px;
        margin-right:10px;
        margin0bottom:0px;
        margin-top:10px;       
}
```

you can also try it out in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/blackknights/2tmqW/embedded/result/

Comment: first of all replace `margin0bottom` with `margin-bottom`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using media queries in CSS. You can read up on them via the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Alternatively, look into responsive web development techniques. Once again, Mozilla has some useful articles and reading material on the subject:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web_Development/Responsive_Web_design

Answer (score 0):

Just set a width on the surrounding div, or the body.  Like so...

```
body {
    width: 960px;
}
```

you can also just set the lower limit by defining `min-width` like so....

```
body {
    min-width: 960px;
}
```